# Cant figure out how to get this function to change just the title associated with the image i clicked on. Always changes All Titles

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I basically cannot figure out how to correctly implement "this". I know "this" refers to the element I click on. I am unsure how to get it to change the title that is associated with the featured images post.

```
 const pic = document.querySelectorAll(".feature img");
 const title = document.querySelector(".title");



$('.feature', this).click(function() {
    console.log(this);
    $('.title').addClass('change');
});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="content">
                <div class="feature"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                    <div class="block">
                        <p class="category uppercase"><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
                            echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
                            } ?></p>
                        <h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <p class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a class="permalink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had to be:

```
$('.feature').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.block').find('.title').addClass('change');
});
```